# Index out of range, but I know the columns are there

Tags: c#, datagridview

EDIT: Found a workaround not using dynamically created tables.

I'm dynamically creating tables using DataGridView in C#. I'm trying to set the column 0 AutoSizeMode but I get the error that index is out of range. However, without ever trying to access columns with code, all my data is displayed properly in the cells, in two columns like it should be.

I tried turning off AutoGenerateColumns, but then I have no data at all.

```
DataGridView mainTable = new DataGridView();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("A");
table.Columns.Add("B");

// ... skipping the part where I populate the data in the table, I know the entire data is truly there...

mainTable.DataSource = table;
mainTable.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: The code where you're trying to set the Columns' width is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it well. I meant the last line of code here throwing an exception that Columns[0] index is our of range. Edited the question.

Comment: Where is the posted code run? In the form load? Button Click?

Comment: @JohnG On button click

Comment: What is the value of `mainTable.Columns.Count`?

Comment: It's equal to 0, as expected, at the moment I try to change AutoSizeMode. In the meanwhile I managed to find a workaround that doesn't use the dynamically created DataGridViews, so I no longer have problems with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confident the reason the line of code…

```
mainTable.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

fails is because the `DataGridView` `mainTable` has NOT yet been added to the form.

Any UI commands issued BEFORE the `DataGridView` is added to the form will be ignored.

Adding the `DataGridView` to the form BEFORE you try and change its columns should work as expected. The posted code does NOT show when the grid is added to the form.

```
DataGridView mainTable = new DataGridView();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("A");
table.Columns.Add("B");
// ... skipping the part where I populate the data in the table, I know the entire data is truly there...
mainTable.DataSource = table;
this.Controls.Add(mainTable); // <- UI commands not ignored
mainTable.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: Tried the following:
```C#
TabPage page = new TabPage();
DataGridView mainTable = new DataGridView();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("A");
table.Columns.Add("B");
// ... skipping the part where I populate the data in the table, I know the entire data is truly there...
mainTable.DataSource = table;
page.Controls.Add(mainTable);
mainTabControl.TabPages.Add(page);
mainTable.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```
And it still throws the same exception

Comment: I am guessing the `TabControl` `mainTabControl` has ALREADY been added to the form AND the tab page `page` is the “active/selected” tab page in the tab control. If the tab page is not active or selected, the UI commands as describe above will still be ignored. The tab page MUST be displayed in order for the UI commands to work. `mainTabControl.SelectedTab = mainTabControl.TabPages[1];`